# create an identity that can issue other identities in hyperledger composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I checked that [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.identity.issue.html) and that there is an option --issuer or -x but what if I want to create an issuer identity from composer rest server ?
what are possible values that can be passed to that "options" field in the body of issue system identity request in the rest server ?

Answer (score 1):

Under /System;

POST /system/identities/issue:

> { "participant": "resource:org.acme.mynetwork.BizAdmin#org1admin",
>   "userID": "jdoe", "options": {"issuer" : true} }

in the JSON data for the request.